# Force cart prices update on checkout page Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

My client requested that the cart is featured at the top of the checkout as well as having it's own page. Everything seems to be working apart from when the user changes either the country of billing or delivery. Due to eu/non eu VAT stuff the prices for the product should change when the item is being shipped outside of the UK. The shipping and totals are updating accordingly.

I'm trying to listen to changes in either of country select fields and have tried calling various triggers but I cannot seem to get the price to update. When you refresh the page manually the correct updated prices are showing. Any help much appreciated, thanks.

```
$('select#billing_country, select#shipping_country').on( 'change', function (){
                var t = { updateTimer: !1,  dirtyInput: !1,
                    reset_update_checkout_timer: function() {
                        clearTimeout(t.updateTimer)
                    },
                    trigger_update_checkout: function() {
                        t.reset_update_checkout_timer(), t.dirtyInput = !1,
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout')
                    }
                };
                //$(document.body).trigger('updated_cart_totals');
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                //$('[name=update_cart]').trigger('click');
                //$( document.body ).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
                //$(document.body).trigger('updated_cart_totals');
                
            });
```

https://esmie-dev.com/checkout/